# Downgrade to Java 6

Tags: java, version, java-6

I have Java 8 installed on my computer, before it was Java 7. But I need to work with version 6.

How can I install Java 6? On Oracle website, it is no longer possible to download the old versions.

How can I downgrade Java if it was not installed before?

Comment: You can download older versions at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html. Note that they should **only** be used for debugging and regression testing purposes - the right approach is to upgrade your application to Java 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be aware that [Java 6 is no longer receiving public updates](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html#Interfaces). You always should use the [most updated Java version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html).

But you can find some historical Java releases on [Oracle Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html). The page warns:

> **WARNING:** These older versions of the JRE and JDK are provided to help developers debug issues in older systems. **They are not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.**

These are the links to download old versions of Java SE:

- [Java SE 8 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html)
- [Java SE 7 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html)
- [Java SE 6 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html)
- [Java SE 5 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html)
- [Java SE 1.4 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html)
- [Java SE 1.3 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase13-419413.html)
- [Java SE 1.2 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase12-419414.html)
- [Java SE 1.1 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase11-419415.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. A lot of notable software can be traced to the very first version (for testing or other purposes). You can actually find and download the first version of Firefox, Chrome, Netbeans, WordPress etc. The same with Java. They just make it a little bit more difficult to dig the [old versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html) up, and they intentionally hide it for good reasons.

> These older versions of the JRE and JDK are provided to help developers debug issues in older systems. They are not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.

and

> Keeping old and unsupported versions of Java on your system presents a serious security risk.

(and Java is already not really reputable, security-wise)

You cannot "downgrade" a certain version of Java. You install different versions of Java you need, and set your project to be built with that specific version. On a system, there can be several Java versions installed together.